# Can Stack Overflow implement single sign on for its all sites?

Tags: support, status-completed, login, authentication

Can Stack Overflow implement single sign on so that users do not have to sign-in again when they visit other Stack Exchange sites like Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, etc.?

Comment: So, so annoying. I share your frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the growth in the number of StackExchange sites the merits of a unified login system are growing as well.

Eventually, logging into StackOverflow will cause you to be logged into, say, [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) too.   All of this is conditioned on you already having an account on both sites.

We've already taken steps in this direction by [unifying logins between parent and child-meta sites](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/).

Answer (score 4):

This is now complete; see

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/

for details

Answer (score 1):

[There are possible reasons why it could not work](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/):

- You’ve been to the target site recently without a global auth session (click the “login” link at the top of every page to force it)
- You’re using some sort of anonymizer that interferes with HTTP Referrer
- You aren’t using the same OpenId across all sites
- You’re visiting a per-site meta without first logging into the parent (child metas don’t use global auth; they rely on identity coming from the parent site.)

Comment: Parent child, left/right, red/black... but which is the parent login? I have the same problem. I'm looking for my question, I can't find it. Be it on superuser, stackexchange, or stack, or stackofpancakes, or stackedonusersonsuperusersonsupersusers

Answer (score -2):

That's somewhat the point of OpenID - if you associate an OpenID with your account, then signing into Stack Exchange site with the same OpenID will automatically import and link your account from other sites.

Comment: No, that's not the same thing. Azhar is asking why you have to sign in separately on each site you visit, even though you're using the same credentials each time.

Comment: @mmyers Curses, confused terminology strikes again! Although "single sign on" meaning "broadcast my identity to anyone who asks" sounds... terrible.