# Why is there no Single sign-on across Stack Exchange Sites?

Tags: feature-request, login, site-crossover, auto-login

I am logged into Stack Overflow using Chrome. But once I'm going to another Stack Exchange site, it asks to log in again.

Why? Is it possible to share authority?

Comment: Some people prefer not to link two accounts (or more) for privacy reasons.

Comment: This is possible, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71239/167646 Does it not work for you?

Comment: Thank you Stijn, this helped