# Does Universal Login not provide single sign-on recently?

Tags: support, login, auto-login

I am a member of a number of Stack Exchange sites. Recently I seem to have gotten logged out from a number of them (Server Fault, Super User) and I can't figure out a way to log in without scrounging in my password manager and copy/pasting e.g. my Stack Overflow password into them.

I thought this used to be a lot easier — for example I found a [2010-era QA related to single sign-on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59293/can-stack-overflow-implement-single-sign-on-for-its-all-sites) tagged as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). I also found a post from 2015 titled [Global auth is dead! Long live universal login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login) that includes these points:

> 1. When you log into any Q&A site on the stackexchange.com domain, you
>      will be automatically logged into all other Q&A sites on the
>      stackexchange.com domain + stackexchange.com itself.
> 2. Area 51 is excluded from this. stackoverflow.com, superuser.com, and
>      other Q&A sites with their own domains will still use the old flow.
> 3. […]

But is there now (in January 2019) no longer a way to just be signed in everywhere? Or am I just noticing this because of item number 2 in the quoted text — if so, what exactly is "the old flow"? What's the easiest way to keep logged into everything Stack Exchange [without staying logged into Google or Facebook *shudder*].

Comment: Do you allow third-party cookies? Mind sharing which browser and OS you're on. Any plugins/extensions running? If you fancy debugging this yourself you might want to read my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309727/how-does-one-stack-exchange-site-know-that-im-logged-in-to-the-other/312956#312956).

Comment: I am currently using Chrome, set to block third party cookies (and with the "uBlock origin" extension). Hoping to switch to Brave soon which I anticipate will be similar. Great writeup, appreciate it!

Comment: Ok, so the SSO is intended to happen whenever you're on a logged-in site, by giving the cross-origin SE properties a chance to set a [considered third-party] cookie. That's great for some users… but I guess there's no auth flow I can use that provides a fallback when such cookies are ignored?

Comment: That is correct, you need to allow third-party cookies. See also what is said in [Stage 3 of the Universal Auth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login) post: *Safari users and users who reject third-party cookies will need to sign in separately to every second-level domain (e.g. stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, etc).*. I guess Adam hoped to find a solution, hence the stage 3 step for the implementation but in the end none of that has worked out. No fallback exists.